# node-mysql use default if null on insert

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm fairly new to mysql, and I'm trying to get up and running with it in node using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql). I have created a simple table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id SERIAL,
    display BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    active BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) DEFAULT CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

I am inserting rows like so:

```
db.query('INSERT INTO myTable SET ?', {
    display: myObject.display,
    active: myObject.active
}, callback);
```

As the docs say, node-mysql converts the object i'm passing in to key value pairs. This works great if `myObject.display` and `myObject.active` are both defined. If one or both aren't, node-mysql tries to insert `NULL` into the columns, which is not allowed. I intended for the default value to be used in this situation, but its throwing an error about the `NULL` value. So my question is:

1) Is there some special syntax to use when creating a table that will use the default when a null value is given, or 2) Is there some elegant way to do this with node-mysql that doesn't involve a bunch of object parsing?

Feel free to expand your answer if you see something else I could improve. My larger goal is to learn the best way to create a robust, safe, and concise mysql insert in node.

Comment: You are combining `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is incorrect for an INSERT statement.

**INSERT**

```
INSERT into TableName(id, display, active)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE TableName SET display = ?
WHERE id = ?
```

You would then populate the `?` placeholders using `db.query()` and passing in your arguments.

Comment: I'm using MySQL, and INSERT ... SET seems to be equivalent to INSERT ... VALUES: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: It also looks like VALUES behaves exactly the same. I still get the error: `Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column \'display\' cannot be null`

Comment: I wouldn't say "exact", I bet the error is different :) - it is indicating that you are passing in a `null` for the "display" column, and it is defined as `NOT NULL`.